# Update SQL multiple rows removing a part of a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a sql table structured like this

```
|[id]--|--[    colour    ]|  
|[ 1]--|--[red_blue_green]|   
|[ 2]--|--[ green_orange ]|   
|[ 3]--|--[  pink_green  ]|   
|[ 4]--|--[     green    ]|
```

What I want to do is to remove green from colours, and to do this I tried this

```
<?php
$del='green';
//DATABASE
require('config.php');
require('connect.php');
$db_content = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM colours WHERE colour LIKE '%_".$del."' OR colour LIKE '%_".$del."_%' OR colour LIKE '".$del."_%' OR colour='$del'");
$rows  = mysql_fetch_row($db_content);
foreach($rows as $row){
  $kaboom = explode('_', $row[6]);
  $i=0;

  while($kaboom[$i]!=$del){
    $i++;
  }

  unset($kaboom[$i]);

  $db_newcontent = implode('_', $kaboom);
  mysql_query("UPDATE colours SET colour='$db_newcontent' WHERE         id='{$row[0]}'");
}
```

But it doesn't work. It gives me no error messages, it only takes a lot of time and then it stops trying. Any suggestions?

Comment: Normalize your schema. And how do you manage to have two colour sets with the same id??

Comment: Had you done what @Strawberry mentioned (normalization), you wouldn't have this problem. Instead of hacking a solution, it's better to take this code you posted and the db structure behind the barn and shoot them dead, then rewrite it properly.

Comment: By the way, the reason this code takes ages and then dies is that you get the first row (ie mysql_fetch_row), then for each field in that first row you explode it into an array on occurrences of underscores. But most fields have no underscores. It then loops while each item in the array is not equal to the value _green_ . But if the array never contains a value of _green_ then that is an endless loop.

Comment: @Kickstart there isn't the possibility that array doesn't contain green, there is something more before this.

Comment: @Strawberry that was a missclick. What do you mean with  normalize?

Comment: @Mjh Do you have any suggestion to rewrite the code properly?

Comment: I do, but you might be better off creating a new question for help with that. I'd create a table which holds color names, then another table that saves color combinations (of course, not by having comma delimited records). I'd use `PDO` instead of `mysql`, which is deprecated since last millenium. In reality, you're looking at ~1.5 hour of work top and a few lines of code.

Comment: Normalisation is *the* fundamental concept underpinning relational databases. In consequence, it's well documented elsewhere, requiring no further rehearsal here.

Comment: @valbuxvb - there is a certainty that the first element won't contain green . You are not looping through the rows, you are looping through the columns in the first row. So $rows contains the columns of the first row, and $row is each column. $row[6] is treating each column as an array and trying to get the 7th element. As the first column is the integer key you are trying to get an empty element into an array and loop through until you find green. But green will NEVER been found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with a single SQL statement.

The following code (assuming your table is called *colour* ) cross joins the table against a pair of sub queries that each return the numbers 0 to 9. This gives 100 copies of each row, with the number 0 to 99. The number is then used to get out each colour, the WHERE clause excludes those which are 'green' and then they are joined back together using GROUP_CONCAT.

```
UPDATE colour a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT colours SEPARATOR '_') AS colour
    FROM
    (
        SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(colour, '_', tens.aCnt * 10 + units.aCnt + 1), '_', -1) AS colours
        FROM colour
        CROSS JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 1 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0
        ) units
        CROSS JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 1 AS aCnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0
        ) tens
        WHERE FIND_IN_SET('green', REPLACE(colour, '_', ','))
    ) sub0
    WHERE colours != 'green'
    GROUP BY id
) b
ON a.id = b.id
SET a.colour = b.colour
```

However having delimited fields in a relational database is normally a very bad idea. For example if you want to search for any record that has the colour green in the list then you cannot use indexes; the database would need to check every single record. You could easily split these off to a separate table with multiple rows for each record on the main table (one for each colour referring to the record on the main table). You can easily get all the values using a table join, and you can easily check for specific values using a query that will use indexes.

EDIT

If you really must use a delimited column and you want to stick with something like your original solution then it can be fixed with something like this:-

```
<?php
$del='green';
//DATABASE
require('config.php');
require('connect.php');
$db_content = mysql_query("SELECT id, colour 
                            FROM colours 
                            WHERE FIND_IN_SET('".mysql_real_escape_string($del)."', REPLACE(colour, '_', ','))");
while ($rows  = mysql_fetch_assoc($db_content))
{
    $kaboom = explode('_', $rows['colour']);
    unset($kaboom[array_search($del, $kaboom)]);

    $db_newcontent = implode('_', $kaboom);
    mysql_query("UPDATE colours 
                    SET colour = '".mysql_real_escape_string($db_newcontent)."' 
                    WHERE id = ".(int)$rows[0]."");
}
```

EDIT again

Example of normalising this.

You have a table of (say) users. This has the id field:-

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name   VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`)
);

INSERT INTO users(id, user_name) VALUES
(1, 'Fred'),
(2, 'Freda'),
(3, 'Jo'),
(4, 'Joe');
```

You then have the table of the colours for each user. This has one row per user per colour (or whatever they have typed in):-

```
CREATE TABLE user_colours
(
    id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    colour  VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
    KEY `colour` (`colour`)
);

INSERT INTO user_colours(id, user_id, colour) VALUES
(1, 1, 'red'),
(2, 1, 'blue'),
(3, 1, 'green'),
(4, 2, 'green');
(5, 2, 'orange');
(6, 3, 'pink');
(7, 3, 'green');
(8, 4, 'green');
```

This way if you need to add an extra colour for a user you just find the id of that user and insert a record in the 2nd table. For example say you wanted to add *pink* for *Freda* you would get the id of Freda which is 2 and then insert a row to the 2nd table like *INSERT INTO user_colours(id, user_id, colour) VALUES(NULL, 2, 'pink')* .

Should you need to delete it then you can easily do it with *DELETE FROM user_colours WHERE user_id = 2 AND colour = 'pink'*

If you want a count of how many users have each colour you could do:-

```
SELECT colour, COUNT(user_id)
FROM user_colours
GROUP BY colour
```

Comment: The problem is that the color values are actually values that user inserts. I don't know how many there will be and that's not a fixed value. I don't really think that is a good idea to make a table and add columns each time user adds a color.

Comment: @valbuxvb That is why you use 2 tables. Then you can have as many elements as the user wants to enter, not limited by the size of the field. Nobody has suggested you add a column each time a user adds a column. You add a row on another table linked to the first table.

Comment: @valbuxvb - I have added more of an explanation on adding an extra table. This is very basic database normalisation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are storing multiple values in a single column.  This is a very bad idea.  You should have a table with one row per color, where you now have a list instead.

Sometimes, though, we are stuck with other people's really bad designs.  You can do what you want:

```
update colours
    set colours = trim(both '_' from replace(concat('_', colours, '_'), '_green_', '_'))
    where concat('_', colours, '_') like '%_green_%';
```

Comment: I made like this because it's the user that inserts colours. I chose colours to make the example easier to understand, actually the user can insert and remove what he wants.

Comment: @valbuxvb . . . Not working is very vague.  How is it not working?  But, you really should fix your application to properly store data in a relational format.

Comment: It doesn't delete green